# Objective-C: What is the actual color of a textfields placeholder text?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, colors, placeholder

I've tried messing with the individual values of red, green, blue. But can't seem to get the color right.

e.g

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.80 green:0.80 blue:0.80 alpha:1.0];
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks to Satish A for pushing me in the right direction.

The UIColor of UITextField.placeholder that I got was

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:196.0/255.0 green:193.0/255.0 blue:110.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

override `drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect` as such to manually render the placeholder text:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

OR

```
[self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:self.textAlignment];
```